# flutter FCM notification

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

The application works perfectly for my knowledge. But I have a problem like this. When the notification arrives, I can't see my notification when the user doesn't open the notification and opens the application after a certain period of time.

sample pictures:

[image: 1]

the problem is here:

[image: 2]

Comment: I think this is intended behaviour. `onMessageOpenedApp` and `getInitialMessage` will only be called if the user clicks on the notification. You can use `FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage` to catch notifications while in the background but is has [limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/receive#background_messages).